# Problem with changing rectangle fill using Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

When I change the rectangle color, clicking on the rectangle color reverts to default

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-gianmarco-swpvf8?file=/src/App.js:0-1287)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8kkc.gif)

I want the color not to change when I click on the rectangle

I found that there is no problem when using react17.0.2 version, for some reason I can't downgrade the process.

Comment: Sandbox not found, Please share your sandbox link properly.